# Convert "Alive" counts per replicate and time to survival data

Tags: r, survival, mortality

I have a raw data set describing survival in groups of individuals over time, organized as follows:

`Diet    Replicate   N   Duration    Alive
A       1           4   0           4
A       2           4   0           4
A       3           4   0           4
A       4           4   0           4
B       1           4   0           4
B       2           4   0           4
...
A       3           4   50          1
A       4           4   50          0
B       1           4   50          0
B       2           4   50          3
B       3           4   50          1
B       4           4   50          2`

`Diet` is the factor, each `Replicate` corresponds to a vial that initially contained a pool of `N` individuals, `Alive` is the number of these initial individuals that are still alive after `Duration`.

When an individual dies, it is removed from the vial but the vial is still being monitored. Note that in this particular data set, empty vials have still been recorded at every `Duration` step with "0" `Alive` instead of just being removed from the monitoring.

Now I would like to analyze this with `survfit()`, but the table is not formatted properly. If I understand correctly, it needs a binary status variable where "1" corresponds to an event (*i.e.*, the death of one individual in a `Replicate` at a given `Duration`) and "0" a non-event (no one died in that particular `Replicate` since the previous monitoring, so individual is censored). <- Am I right?

I suppose that if two individuals from one `Replicate` died at a given time, two consecutive rows of "1" would be required for the corresponding `Replicate` and `Duration`, meaning that in fact my table should not group by replicates but instead unfold all individuals in rows (one row per individual instead of one per `Replicate` of `N`=4 individuals).

I managed to get the bigger table with one individual per row and a `Mortality` binary variable where "1" means Dead and "0" means Alive, but I believe this does not correspond to a status variable: an individual reported as Dead (1) at a given time will still be described as Dead the next time, and `survfit()` will consider it a new mortality event. I imagine that what I would need is to convert Dead (a descriptor for a given individual) into Death (an unique event) by removing duplicates of `Mortality`=1 once Death has already occurred for that particular individual.

I tried out of curiosity with `fit=survfit(Surv(Duration, Mortality)~Diet, data=surv)`, and it runs without complaints, but the counts are broken: it seems that each individual is counted multiple times (once per time-point), resulting in a `n.risk` much higher than my actual sample size; see the summary output with my actual data below:

`Call: survfit(formula = Surv(Duration, Mortality) ~ Diet, data = surv)

Diet=A 
 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
   11   2556     114   0.9554 0.00408       0.9474       0.9634
   15   2336     134   0.9006 0.00600       0.8889       0.9124
   18   2116      95   0.8602 0.00702       0.8465       0.8740
   22   1976     146   0.7966 0.00824       0.7806       0.8129
   25   1756     150   0.7286 0.00922       0.7107       0.7469
   28   1540     160   0.6529 0.01002       0.6335       0.6728
   30   1320     165   0.5713 0.01059       0.5509       0.5924
   32   1100     170   0.4830 0.01090       0.4621       0.5048
   36    880     174   0.3875 0.01089       0.3667       0.4094
   39    660     175   0.2847 0.01041       0.2650       0.3059
   42    440     179   0.1689 0.00909       0.1520       0.1877
   59   [220]    180   0.0307 0.00469       0.0228       0.0414

Diet=B 
 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
    9   2688     190    0.929 0.00494      0.91968       0.9391
   16   2464     198    0.855 0.00682      0.84137       0.8681
   18   2240     198    0.779 0.00806      0.76345       0.7951
   22   2016     199    0.702 0.00892      0.68492       0.7199
   25   1792     199    0.624 0.00949      0.60589       0.6431
   28   1568     201    0.544 0.00981      0.52531       0.5638
   30   1344     201    0.463 0.00988      0.44384       0.4826
   32   1120     201    0.380 0.00969      0.36123       0.3992
   36    896     202    0.294 0.00919      0.27667       0.3127
   39    672     202    0.206 0.00827      0.19014       0.2226
   42    448     203    0.113 0.00662      0.10025       0.1263
   59   [224]    204    0.010 0.00222      0.00651       0.0155`

The values I've put in brackets are my actual number of initial individuals in each Diet, *i.e.*, the values I should have at time=0.

I suspect this is because `survfit()` assumes death events are recorded, and not dead individuals, but I am not sure how to convert the data to the proper format. I'd be very grateful if someone could give me any pointers on how to do that without re-typing the raw data accordingly.